# A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-restart'

Tags: react-native, build, version, updates, compiler-warnings

I don't know what happened in the build please help me to find the issue.
I'm doing upgrade my react-native app from 0.64.2 to 0.72.1

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-restart'.

> No signature of method: build_afxi0qx2ay1lg1ud0qnu4nfni.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_afxi0qx2ay1lg1ud0qnu4nfni$_run_closure1) values: [build_afxi0qx2ay1lg1ud0qnu4nfni$_run_closure1@1fae07c5]

where

```js
def safeExtGet(name) {
  rootProject.ext.has(name) ? rootProject.ext.get(name) : project.properties[name]
}

android {
  namespace 'co m.reactnativerestart'

  compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion')

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion')
    targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('targetSdkVersion')
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
```

```js
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
        firebaseIidVersion = "18.0.0"
        kotlin_version = '1.6.10' // <- add this line
    }
```

I'm trying to solve the issue but it not resolved please guide me for the solution